# Replace all possible text inside a HTML-element with asterix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, element

I was wondering if there is any way to change all text inside a HTML-element to an asterix.

```
<div id="1">
Text
<div>
text
    <span>text</span>
</div></div>
```

So that it would replace all the 'text' in the sample above with '****' by only targeting the div with id '1'.

Comment: You need to traverse the DOM changing the `textContent` of all text nodes you find under that `div`. -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/4okxq7qf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace any alpha-numeric characters with an asterix, use:

```
$('#1').contents().each(function(){
    var prop = this.nodeType === 3 ? 'nodeValue' : 'innerText';
    this[prop] = this[prop].replace(/\w/g,'*');
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Can you please explain what that if statement does?

Comment: That's to handle textnode on which you cannot use `ìnnerText`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just call `.text()`:

```
var content = $('#1').text().trim();
$('#1').text( new Array( content.length + 1 ).join('*') );
```

Comment: Doesn't work like this. What about elements§?  EDIT: this is what OP is looking for, well...

Comment: only thing is that this doesn't work with a table inside the div. because it deletes de <table> and <tr> tags

Answer (score 0):

$("#1").replaceWith("******");

Use replaceWith method .

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("#1").replaceWith("******");
    });
});
</script>
```

For changing On page load use  this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

           $("#1").replaceWith("******");

    });
    </script>
```